# Flask - Apps in multiple folders

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am experimenting with Flask and PythonAnywhere. I have a number of Flask projects that I've created while learning, and I would like to link to them all from a 'master' Flask page.

```
Projects
-- Weather
---- app.py
---- static
---- templates

-- Coin Toss
---- app.py
---- static
---- templates

-- etc.
```

What is the best way to combine all these files/folders?

Answer (score 1):

*PythonAnywhere.com* only supports **one** web app on the beginner plan.

Best solution would be to create new project and in `app.py` index route(endpoint) add custom routes to all other projects.

Example:

`/weather` -> Route to weather app, where all code from `Weather/app.py` is put in `/weather` route.

`/coin_toss` -> Route to Coin Toss app, where all code from `Coin Toss/app.py` is put in `/weather` route

`/index` -> To select *Weather* or *Coin Toss* or some other project on custom route(path).

**EDIT:**

Example how would you do it

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    #  Just put all html in index.html
    #  return render_template('index.html')
    return "<body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('coin_toss') }}">Coin Toss</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('weather_app') }}">Weather App</a>
    ...
</body>"


@app.route("/coin_toss")
def coin_toss():

    # Code for coin toss

    return render_template('coin_toss.html')


@app.route("/weather_app")
def weather_app():

    # Code for weather app

    return render_template('weather_app.html')
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinko! Could you provide a basic Hello World with this structure. I am struggling and can't find any examples with my Google skills.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the following Help page, it seems that you can in fact do as you want to do by using DispatcherMiddleware, allowing you to keep your applications in their original structure.

[PythonAnywhere help topic](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12478/)